# How can i open sub-library's activity from Parent Project

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-libraries, android-library

i am facing some android sub-module or aar lib problem.

I have one parent project and I want to add a different project into the my parent project (containing DI, network, activity, fragment). I think I have added successfully. My workspace looks like below screen shoot.

[image]

i also added in app gradle
`implementation project(":GaleriDemo")` 
and added in settings.gradle

[image]

But when I try to open a sub-module activity in a click event in the Parent project. It doesn't open properly for some reason.

My library have some basic configuration for build like below screen shoot.

[image: ExampleLibrary Config]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i tried like this to open my sub-module activity [image]

[image: After i clicked behavior]

When i clicked the button i am facing above screen shot behavior (like opening same activity in fragment.). But it should be opening my sub-module TestMainActivity, so i think i missed some configuration or some packageName settings. Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the layout resource in the problem sub-module and the names in the parent projects are the same. When I edit the layout names, my problem was solved.